# how to store media files downloaded from server as not accessible to users

Tags: android, file, cordova

I am writing a phonoe gap + android application. In the application, I want to download music files from the server and when he downloads files, he can play it using my application. problem is I don't want user to backup and share files that he downloaded from the server . For these music files, user has to pay.

when I check android system, I cant see any application installation folder for my application.
Is it good idea to store downloaded music in my application installation folder?
I dont encript music files but I want to store them application installation folder.

Is this possible with phone gap? Please give me your idea or any hint

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the music file inside your app using `/data/data/you app package name`. As per requirement, I would give a condition check to see if the user has made payment, if he has then access media files located in app, else access file located on sd-card.

Comment: I didnt find a methode from phonegap api to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have any idea of PhoneGap.This is what I would do in order to save to solve the issue.(Development IDE would be Eclipse)